# GET info from external API/URL using PHP

Tags: php

I have the URL http://api.minetools.eu/ping/play.desnia.net/25565 which outputs statistics of my server.

For example:

```
{
  "description": "A Minecraft Server",
  "favicon": null,
  "latency": 64.646,
  "players": {
    "max": 20,
    "online": 0,
    "sample": []
  },
  "version": {
    "name": "Spigot 1.8.8",
    "protocol": 47
  }
}
```

I want to get the value of online player count to display it on my website as: Online Players: online amount

Can anyone help?

I tried to do:

```
<b> Online players: 

<?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://api.minetools.eu/ping/play.desnia.net/25565");
echo ($content, ["online"]);
}
?>
</b>
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 41):

**1) Don't use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)** (If you can help it)

This is because you'd need to [enable `fopen_wrappers`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) to enable [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to work on an external source. Sometimes this is closed (depending on your host; like shared hosting), so your application will break.

Generally a good alternative is [`curl()`](http://php.net/curl)

**2) Using [`curl()`](http://php.net/curl) to perform a `GET` request**

This is pretty straight forward. Issue a `GET` request with some headers using [`curl()`](http://php.net/curl).

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.minetools.eu/ping/play.desnia.net/25565",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

**3) Using the response**

The response comes back in a [JSON object](http://www.json.org/). We can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to put this into a usable object or array.

```
$response = json_decode($response, true); //because of true, it's in an array
echo 'Online: '. $response['players']['online'];
```

Comment: @hd, I am using a proxy to connect to the internet. The file_get_content works but the curl option throws a "Cache Access Denied." and "Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request http://freegeoip.net/json/X.X.X.X from this cache until you have authenticated yourself."

Answer (score 9):

Your server is returning a JSON string.
So you should use **json_decode()** function to convert that into a plain PHP object.
Thereafter you can access any variable of that object.

So, something like this shall help

```
<?php
$content =     file_get_contents("http://api.minetools.eu/ping/play.desnia.net/25565");

$result  = json_decode($content);

print_r( $result->players->online );
?>
```

More details for json_decode can be read here -
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2):

Your webservice (URL: http://api.minetools.eu/ping/play.desnia.net/25565) returns [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

This is a standard format, and PHP (at least since 5.2) supports decoding it natively - you'll get some form of PHP structure back from it.

Your code currently doesn't work (your syntax is meaningless on the `echo` - and even if it was valid, you're treating a string copy of the raw JSON data as an array - which won't work), you need to have PHP *interpret* (decode) the JSON data first:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
<?php
$statisticsJson = file_get_contents("http://api.minetools.eu/ping/play.desnia.net/25565");
$statisticsObj = json_decode($statisticsJson);
```

Your `$statisticsObj` will be `NULL` if an error occurred - and you can get that error using other standard PHP functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Assuming it isn't `NULL`, you can examine the structure of the object with `var_dump($statisticsObj)` - and then alter your code to print it out appropriately.

In short, something like:

```
<?php
$statisticsJson = file_get_contents("http://api.minetools.eu/ping/play.desnia.net/25565");
$statisticsObj = json_decode($statisticsJson);
if ($statisticsObj !== null) {
   echo $statisticsObj->players->online;
} else {
   echo "Unknown";
}
```

You should also check what comes back from `file_get_contents()` too - various return values can come back (which would blow up `json_decode()`) on errors.  See the documentation for possibilities:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

I'd also wrap the entire thing in a function or class method to keep your code tidy.  A simple "almost complete" solution could look like this:

```
<?php
function getServerStatistics($url) {
    $statisticsJson = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($statisticsJson === false) {
       return false;
    }

    $statisticsObj = json_decode($statisticsJson);
    if ($statisticsObj !== null) {
       return false;
    }

    return $statisticsObj;
}

// ...

$stats = getServerStatistics($url);
if ($stats !== false) {
    print $stats->players->online;
}
```

If you want better handling over server / HTTP errors etc, I'd look at using `curl_*()` - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Ideally you also should be confirming the structure returned from your webservice is what you expected before blindly making assumptions too.  You can do that with something like `property_exists()`.

Happy hacking!

Comment: Nice, though refine the `getServerStatistics()` function. `$url` isn't being used.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's returning an array you should use print_r or var_dump instead of echo. Or perhaps it threw you an error.