# Get API Endpoint values with Key?

Tags: php, api, endpoint

I'm very new to API endpoints, so I would appreciate any help at all, but what I'm trying to do is grab data from an API endpoint - and parse the information on to a page using php.

I am not sure if some kind soul out there might have a better method in mind, but essentially, I am trying to display all instances of "unit_number" from my API here...  would anyone be able to possibly steer me in the right direction?

There's also a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302442/get-info-from-external-api-url-using-php) -- but I'm not sure how I would be able to add the API Key to append the url?  Again ANY help would be appreciated, I spent the night looking at how to do this, and can get the api results to at least show up in postman but I'm not sure how I could do the same in php?

---

There's a few areas I think I'm stuck on, but essentially, what I am trying to do is with this code:

```
<?php

$api               =   'APIURL';    
$token             =   'APINUMBEREDKEYHERE';

$options            =   [
'http'          =>  [
    'method'    =>  'GET',
    'header'    =>  "Authorization: Bearer $token"
]
];

$context            =   stream_context_create( $options );

$results            =   file_get_contents( $api, false, $context );
$results            =   json_decode( $results );
?>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center">Droplet ID</th>
        <
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php
foreach ( $results as $droplets )
{
foreach ( $droplets as $droplet )
{
    if ( isset( $droplet->unit_number ) )
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $droplet->unit_number; 
?></td>

    </tr>
<?php
    }
}
}
?>
</table>
?>
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having? Have you tried debugging the values you get back from the API? FYI, your HTML table is malformed. You should ideally be adding the main section to a `<tbody>` element. You also have an extra `</thead>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, I'm trying to connect to an API endpoint.... I'm not sure how to do this, but what I would like to do is reference the below API like they have provided and use the API_Key to integrate the JSON results onto a page which can then be styled.  The client only provided me this:

API Endpoint URL: https://api.urlhere
API key required as a header 'API-Key' => 'APIKEYCODEHERE'

I just don't know how I can do that in php... kind of going down the rabbit hole tying to figure this out.   I can remove my code in my initial question if that helps?