# I need to pull data from a remote PHP file, into an array

Tags: php, arrays

A remote PHP (that I do a php include with) file returns this data:

{"temp":"57.6","dev":"0.4","city":"Williamston","country":"United States","count":"72690"}

I want to take that data and load it into an array so I can do things with it, and I'm stuck with that part. :-) Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried different syntax as you see in what I'm trying to display.

```
<?php include("filename.php"); ?>
<?php
    function data() {
        $datalist = array(
           "currenttemp" => "temp",
           "deviation" => "dev",
           "last_processed"   => "city",
           "country" => "country",
       "stations_processed" => "count",
        ); } ?>


<table width="280" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Current World Temp:</td>
  <td><?php echo $datalist[0]["temp"]; ?></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Deviation:</td>
  <td><?php print "$deviation"; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Last Station Processed:</td>
  <td><?php print "$last_processed"; ?>, <?php print "$country"; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>tations Processed Last Hour:</td>
  <td><?php print "$stations_processed"; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The data looks like a JSON string, so you can use `json_decode()`. Demo: https://3v4l.org/GfOsQ

Comment: If you want an associative array rather than an object as the result, just set the 2nd argument to true. Demo: https://3v4l.org/l5Ub6 . Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and set the second parameter to true, so it will be converted into array:

```
json_decode('{"temp":"57.6","dev":"0.4","city":"Williamston","country":"United States","count":"72690"}', true)
```

Comment: Still not quite following. This is the link to the data. 
https://temperature.global/api.php

Comment: It should go into a table like this
 <table width="280" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Current World Temp:</td>
      <td><?php print "$currenttemp"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Deviation:</td>
      <td><?php print "$deviation"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Station Processed:</td>
      <td><?php print "$last_processed"; ?>, <?php print "$country"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tations Processed Last Hour:</td>
      <td><?php print "$stations_processed"; ?></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

Comment: @SteveBrueck what part are you unable to follow? Remember you haven't actually shown us how you get the data from the remote API, you've simply stated that you've done it. So we've started from that point. And we've shown you how to get the data into an array, which is what you asked. Outputting that data into a HTML table structure is the next step after that. You didn't ask about that. But there should be plenty of examples online showing the general process of getting data from an array into a HTML table using PHP. If you get stuck with that after you've tried, you can ask about it

Comment: I can get the data into the table if I can get it into an array. 
I was trying to use an php include that I stated in the original post.

<?php include("https://temperature.global/api.php"); ?>

Comment: The api.php file returns this:
{"temp":"57.6","dev":"0.4","city":"Williamston","country":"United States","count":"72690"}

Of course the values returned will always be changing, but the field news remain the same. 
I need to convert that to an array. After that, I can do the rest.

Comment: @SteveBrueck your original question simply says you did `include("filename.php");`. It doesn't say that that was actually the API file. We assumed maybe there was some code in there to _call_ the API. But remember that `include` doesn't actually return any data. It simply causes the PHP in that file to be executed. However if the file in question is on a remote server where you don't have access to it then that won't work. So I think _really_ your question is actually "how do I call a remote API and get the response into a variable?"...

Comment: @SteveBrueck ...to which the answer would generally be to use cURL, or for very simple requests (like this one seemingly), something like `file_get_contents()` would do the job. e.g. `$json = file_get_contents("https://temperature.global/api.php"); $data = json_decode($json, true);` . Unlike `include`, that doesn't attempt to treat the data it gets back as PHP code and then execute it, rather it gets the _output_ of requesting that URL via HTTP - which in this case will be the JSON data - and then you can put it into a variable and use it. P.S.: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.p

Comment: @SteveBrueck ... and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: @SteveBrueck happy to help! If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @ADyson, I'll be more than happy to do that, but I'm not seeing where to do it.

Comment: @it wasn't me who made that comment. You can't mark my comments as answers. You can mark the answer that this comment thread comes from as accepted if you think _that_ answers the question, but that wasn't the impression I got of what had happened. As your question is currently closed I can't add an answer of my own - but I'd guess your issue is a duplicate of an older question anyway, it's not really a new problem. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33303776/5947043